# How to only send Algolia specific fields from a document in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am new to using Algolia. I'm trying to send user data to Aloglia from my Firestore so that I can search for them later in the app I am creating. I've successfully set everything up, all my functions work via the Firebase cloud function. So when I create a document for 'users' in Firestore it passes all of the fields to Algolia, updating and deleting this data is also manifested in Algolia.

However, for the sake of maintaining security, I do not want to send ALL of the user data to Algolia, but rather only a few fields. These include 'displayName' and 'username' (two of the fields in the 'users' collection).

So my question is how do I change my code to only send those two fields to Algolia?
Please provide an answer for delete and update as well.

My Code:

```html
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

const ALGOLIA_APP_ID = "MY KEY";
const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = "MY KEY";
const ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = "users";

var client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);


admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userID}')
.onCreate( async (snap, context) => {
    const newValue = snap.data();
    newValue.objectID = snap.id;

    var index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
    index.saveObject(newValue);
});

exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userID}')
    .onUpdate( async (snap, context) => {
        const afterUpdate = snap.after.data();
        afterUpdate.objectID = snap.after.id;
        
        var index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
        index.saveObject(afterUpdate);
    })

exports.deleteUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userID}/')
    .onDelete( async (snap, context) => {
        const oldID = snap.id;

        var index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
        index.deleteObject(oldID);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algolia has some [good documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/methods/indexing/) on how to perform add, update, and delete operations on an index. Note that for adding and updating you will need to pass `objectID`.

#### Add only certain fields

Using some of the code from your example, here is how you could pass only certain fields of your Firestore object to Algolia ([example from docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/add-objects/#add-a-single-object)):

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{userId}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const newValue = snap.data();
        const user = {
            objectID: context.params.userId,
            displayName: newValue.displayName,
            username: newValue.username,
        };

        return index.saveObject(user);
    });
```

#### Update only certain fields

Also inspired by [an example in the docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/partial-update-objects/#update-only-the-city-attribute-of-an-existing-object):

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{userId}")
    .onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
        const afterUpdate = snap.after.data();
        const updateUser = {
            objectID: context.params.userId,
            displayName: afterUpdate.displayName,
            username: afterUpdate.username,
        };

        await index.partialUpdateObject(updateUser);
    });
```

#### Deleting

It is possible to [delete by filters](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/delete-by/), though I've not done this, and the docs indicate that you should use the `deleteObject` method instead because it is more performant. You can do:

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.firestore
    .document("users/{userId}")
    .onDelete((snap) => {
        return index.deleteObject(snap.id);
    });
```